# jquery toggle on click not working

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble figuring out why I am not able to use the following function to change the style of a element with the click function.  This is strange because when I use this exact same code with "Hover" it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".category").click(function() {
          $(".category-nav").css("display", "none");
          },
          function(){
            $(".category-nav").css("display", "block");
      });

});
```

Comment: Unlike .hover(), click() only accepts one function. Reading the documentation would've told you this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can get desired behavior, by using: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ *toggle* function.

Something like:

```
$(".category").click(function() {
          $(".category-nav").toggle();
          });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ppeh0cgf/

Answer (score 0):

Click only accepts one function, try changing your click function to something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="category">
Click here
  <div class="category-nav">
  TEST
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
show {
  display: block;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
 $(".category").click(function() {
   var elem = $(".category-nav");
   if (elem.hasClass("hide")) {
     elem.removeClass("hide");
     elem.addClass("show");
   } else {
     elem.removeClass("show");
     elem.addClass("hide");

   }
 });
```

See [Example.](https://jsfiddle.net/gymLm8ur/)